# PHP Imagick not working on Windows 10 MAMP

Tags: php, windows, mamp, imagick

I'm working on a local project on a Windows 10 machine in a Mamp environment with PHP 7.1.5. When I use imagick for creating new images it works without problems but if it has to work on images already present in the root of the site crashes. I've tried all solutions but not working.

This is the code I am using for the test

```
<?php

    try {
          $image = new Imagick('draw.jpg');
          $resolutions = $image->identifyImage ();
          echo 'res:' . $resolutions['format'];

    } catch (ImagickException $e) {
          var_dump($e);
    }

?>
```

This is the error dump:

```
object(ImagickException)#2 (7) { ["message":protected]=> string(83)
"UnableToOpenBlob `draw.jpg': No such file or directory @
error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657"
```

P.S: on mac os with mamp it works perfectly. HELP ME!

Comment: The error says that the file does not exist. Have you tried specifying the full path?

Comment: the file exist is accessible at url: localhost/site/draw.jpg and test.php is in the same root

Comment: Get PHP to print the current working directory.

Comment: Done...this is the result: C:\MAMP\htdocs\site